# Add stock EOD data to Amibroker using c#

Tags: c#

Is anyone give me some sample code how add stock EOD data to amibroker using AmiBroker Plug-ins with C#. I download 'AmiBroker Plug-ins with C#' from amibroker.codeplex.com. it does not have any documention how to add EOD data into a stock.

Answer (score 1):

Basically all you need is just to add information about your plug-in inside Plugin.cs/GetPluginInfo() method and quotes related logic into Plugin.cs/GetQuotesEx(). For example:

```
public static unsafe int GetQuotesEx(string ticker, Periodicity periodicity,
                                     int lastValid, int size, Quotation* quotes,
                                     GQEContext* context)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        quotes[i].DateTime = new AmiDate(DateTime.Now.AddDays(i - 5));
        quotes[i].Price = 10;
        quotes[i].Open = 15;
        quotes[i].High = 16;
        quotes[i].Low = 9;
        quotes[i].Volume = 1000;
        quotes[i].OpenInterest = 0;
        quotes[i].AuxData1 = 0;
        quotes[i].AuxData2 = 0;
    }

    return 5;
}
```

For more info visit: http://github.com/kriasoft/amibroker